# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'name' not readable

Tags: java, jsp

I have tried all the solution given in the similar questions but nothing is working.

Servlet class:

```
test t = new test();
t.setName("abcd");
request.setAttribute("t", t);
RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
req.forward(request, response);
```

test class:

```
class test{

    String name;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

and in jsp file I'm doing: `${t.name}<br>`
but it results in a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`

Comment: I wonder if making the test class public would make a difference?

Comment: You left out the most important piece, which is how you obtained the `t` reference in your JSP.